# Google Maps API - Cant't find autocomplete suggested text

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I need to use autocomplete on Google Maps but I don't want users to have to click on  suggestions in order to find locations.

If we copy texts that are suggested in autocomplete:

http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

and paste them on geocoding example:

http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geocoding-simple.html

sometimes Google can't find them and sometimes it finds wrong locations.

Example: **Shopping Center Norte - Travessa Casalbuono, São Paulo, Brasil**

Does somebody know how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

The geocoder is just that - a geocoder. A Geocoder understands addresses - and tries to turn them into coordinates.

It does not understand business names. So the business name at the beginning of the string, will confuse the geocoder.

Don't try to pass business names to the geocoder.

Why are you even trying? The autocomplete data contains coordiantes.

Comment: Sometimes user just write and search without clicking on autocomplete suggestions. Google maps website works fine but I can't get it done by using their public API.